# Write only uncaught exception in php

Tags: php, exception

I have a code like this that generate ( with some parameter, an exception ):

```
$test = new MyClass($withParameter);
```

it realease a CustomException and I would catch it with a try, without letting PHP write it down in the html.

So i tried with:

```
try{
    $test = new MyClass($withParameter);
}catch(CustomException $exc){
    log("handled exc");
}
```

but it continue to write all the backtrace in the flow, even if I handled it.
Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: try this: try { ... code .. } catch (Exception $e) { log("Exception is of type:".get_class($e)); }  and report back what you get please

Comment: If Cillier's suggestion doesn't help you, try creating a minimal example that demonstrates the issue, your code above isn't enough.